# Weird uninitialized constant error (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base     
  def self.get  
     today = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York').utc_to_local(Time.now.utc).to_date
  end    
end
```

produces the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Schedule::TZInfo
```

but only when I'm **not** running it from script/console. Thoughts?

(Also, is there a better way to get the current date in a given time zone?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding

```
require 'tzinfo'
```

Comment: This works, but I already added a `config.gem` line in `environment.rb` -- shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: I believe that just makes sure that the gem is installed - it doesn't necessarily include it 8(