# Problem With Autocomplete field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am trying to implement SO style autocomplete.  I am using this gem to download the necessary rails3-jquery-autocomplete.

Here is my controller:

```
autocomplete :tag, :name
```

My layout has this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "autocomplete-rails.js"  %>
```

My routes has this:

```
resources :posts do
    get :autocomplete_tag_name, :on => :collection    
 end
```

And my form has this:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ', :class => "tags" %>
```

I have the autocomplete-rails.js in my public/javascript folder. Yet for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `autocomplete_field' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x0000011cb94ef8>.
```

My environment.rb file looks like this:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
NutraNation::Application.initialize!
```

What am I doing wrong? Some help would leave me forever in your debt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is a Rails error, not a javascript error. The error basically means you're calling a helper method (`autocomplete_field`) that doesn't exist.

Looks like you're not including the auto_complete gem in the right place. Check your `%APP_ROOT/config/environment.rb` file, and make sure your gem is included there.

Also, make sure you've included any necessary resources in your helper. Install instructions for the gem should explain any/all things you need to check to make sure it's setup correctly.

Comment: How do you add file to your environment.rb file? Mine looks like this:# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
NutraNation::Application.initialize!

Comment: config.gem 'the name of the gem'

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246671/what-does-config-gem-in-environment-rb-do

Comment: Also see this example file, from a production application: https://github.com/normalocity/feelgoodtrader/blob/master/config/environment.rb Note all the lines that start with "config.gem ...."